# Angular conditions ng-show by category

Tags: angularjs

How can i, using angularjs, ng-show only one time the name of the category, how can i assign a previous-category variable to match this condition ?

```
Eg. 
Animals, orc, sea;
Animals, dolphin, sea;
Animals, lion, land;
Fruits, apple, red;
Fruits, orange, citric;

<tr ng-repeat="singularitem in item ">
     <td ng-show="{{category != previous-category}}" colspan=2>{{ singularitem.Category }}</td>
            <td>{{ singularitem.Category }}</td>
            <td>{{ singularitem.Object}}</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using `ng-init`. see the example

```
<tr ng-repeat="singularitem in item ">
     <td ng-show="{{singularitem.Category != previous-category}}" ng-init="previous-category = singularitem.Category " colspan=2>{{ singularitem.Category }}</td>
            <td>{{ singularitem.Category }}</td>
            <td>{{ singularitem.Object}}</td>
```

And in controller you should declare `previous-category` as a blank string variable first. Do it in your controller

```
$scope.previous-category = '';
```

Comment: Hi Vinnet i try but only prints the value 0 in the previous-category.